# Бот бесконтрольно присылает сообщения

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegraf

Пишу бота на node.js с использованием библиотеки telegraf.js. Иногда при запуске бота через консоль он начинает в рандомный момент диалога спамить сообщениями, всеми подряд. В целом у меня почти к каждому сообщению прикручена кнопка "продолжить" но бот не дожидаясь даже нажатия на кнопку начинает просто слать поток сообщений. Проверил обработчики - всё нормально, убедился что создаётся только один экземпляр бота, и это **100% не отложенные сообщения**, которые могут приходить пока бот был оффлайн. Кода много поэтому не прикрепляю. Но самые очевидные вещи проверил - ошибок нет. Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?